# return value of function looping through list in reverse is the last element in it

Tags: python, list, loops

this function is supposed to return the list in reverse but instead, it is only returning the last element of the list. I would like to know what is the issue.

```
def reverse_list(lt):
    for f in lt[::-1]:
        return f
lt = [1,2,3,4]
print(reverse_list(lt))
```

Comment: try : `return lt[::-1]`

Comment: If you return in a for loop, how many iterations do you think that for loop does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def reverse_list(lt):
    return lt[::-1]

lt = [1,2,3,4]
print(reverse_list(lt))
```